# How Do I create a custom sxa component in Sitecore 9.3?

Tags: sxa

I am having a hard time creating a custom sxa search component for sitecore 9.3. Is there an example anywhere that someone can link me to?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I want to search through my item based on the location set in each. I set the location by inheriting from IPoi, so these are coordinates. I want to search by city and/or zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link for Sitecore documentation where you can find a step by step documentation for how you can create SXA custom rendering:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/walkthrough--building-a-simple-rendering.html

Moreover, follow this chart to decide when to go with a custom rendering:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/flowchart-to-determine-whether-to-create-a-custom-rendering.html